# What does the term "empty loop" refer to exactly in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c

Is it this kind of thing:

```
for(;;)
 {
   statements;
 }
```

Or is it this:

```
for(initialisation;condition;updation)
{
}
```

I am looking for answers with references to a variety of sources.

Comment: Read also: [Is an (empty) infinite loop undefined behavior in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595493/is-an-empty-infinite-loop-undefined-behavior-in-c)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Your first case (*for* with empty expressions) is an **infinite** loop and the second one (with empty body of the *for* statement) is an **empty** loop

Comment: For the record, the body of an empty lop can be explicitly omitted too: `for(initialisation;condition;updation);`

Comment: @Péter Yes, and that empty statement is called a 'null statement'. Applies to 'while' statements as well.

Comment: and the two are not mutexive: `for(;;);` is an empty infinite loop!

Answer (score 6):

In my environment it is like this:

```
for(;;) { statements; }
```

endless loop

```
for(initialisation;condition;updation) { }
```

empty loop

Answer (score 2):

Answer is context dependent.

If you mean an empty **for** loop, then

```
 for(;;)
 {
     statements;
 }
```

is such a thing.

Although, the same thing can be achieved with a while loop:

```
while(true)
{
    statements;
}
```

and this isn't an "empty" loop. Both of these are infinite loops that you must break out of using `break` inside of your loop.

On the other hand,

```
for(initialisation;condition;updation)
{
}
```

this is an "empty" loop that bascially does nothing, except perhaps update some variables that could be defined before the loop itself.

Comment: The last for-loop could very well do lots and lots of things, because the updatestatement can have all sorts of side effects - if you wanted to you could stuff most of your application in it. I certainly advise against it from maintainability point of view, but assuming that the last 'basically does nothing' when you find such a loop in unknown code certainly isn't wise.

Comment: I think you need to edit, you're claiming that the first `for` loop is both empty and not empty.

Comment: Example of a place an empty loop could do something: `while( ((c=getchar()) != '\n') && (c != EOF)) {}` (where `c` is an `int`). Seeks through `stdin` to the first found newline or end of stream.

Answer (score 2):

An empty loop is a loop which has an empty body, e.g.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {}
while(cin) {}
```

(note that the second example here also happens to be endless)

There are cases where these are useful, for example when a function has a desired side-effect and returns its success, and should repeated until unsuccessful, for example to read the last line in a file:

```
std::string getLastLine(std::string filename)
{
  std::ifstream in(filename.c_str());
  if(!in)
    return "";

  std::string line;
  while(std::getline(in, line)); // empty loop, the operation returns the condition
  return line;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It equals to that:

```
while (true) {
  statements;
}
```

Infinite for loop is a loop that works until something else stops it.

Comment: @Martin, I commented on the answer itself, not your comment - sorry for the confusion :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
for(;;)
 {
   statements;
 }
```

is endless loop because there is redundant value/Grabage value which makes the loop true

```
for(initialisation;condition;updation)
 {
   body;
 }
```

is just syntax for for loop (educational purpose use)