# Thread Synchronization at C

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization

I have to use two threads; one to do various operations on matrices, and the other to monitor virtual memory at various points in the matrix operation process. This method is required to use a global state variable 'flag'.

So far I have the following (leaving some out for brevity):

```
int flag = 0;

int allocate_matrices(int dimension)
{
    while (flag == 0) {} //busy wait while main prints memory state

    int *matrix = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*dimension*dimension);
    int *matrix2 = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*dimension*dimension);

    flag = 0;
    while (flag == 0) {} //busy wait while main prints memory state

    // more similar actions...
}

int memory_stats()
{
    while (flag == 0)
    { system("top"); flag = 1; }
}

int main()
{ //threads are created and joined for these two functions }
```

As you might expect, the `system("top")` call happens once, the the matrices are allocated, then the program falls into an infinite loop. It seems apparent to me that this is because the thread assigned to the `memory_stats` function has already completed its duty, so flag will never be updated again.

Is there an elegant way around this? I know I have to print memory stats four times, so it occurs to me that I could write four while loops in the `memory_stats` function with busy waiting contingent on the global flag in between each of them, but that seems clunky to me. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Not use threads? Because in this case it doesn't make any sense. Or use mutex, or atomic primitives.

Comment: You should be using Pthreads for this.  https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Comment: @VladLazarenko You're right, it doesn't make sense. I realize that all of this could easily be done sequentially and would do it that way if I had the choice. If I used a mutex, which occurred to me as well, would the theory be any different? That is, would I have a more elegant solution than writing four loops with intermittent busy waiting?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am using pthreads. In the main function, pthreads are created and joined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the possible reasons for the hang is that `flag` is a regular variable and the compiler sees that it's never set to a non-zero value between `flag = 0;` and `while (flag == 0) {}` or in this `while` inside `allocate_matrices()`. And so it "thinks" the variable stays 0 and the loop becomes infinite. The compiler is entirely oblivious to your threads.

You could define `flag` as `volatile` to prevent the above from happening, but you'll likely run into other issues after adding `volatile`. For one thing, `volatile` does not guarantee atomicity of variable modifications.

Another issue is that if the compiler sees [an infinite loop that has no side effects, it *may be* considered undefined behavior and anything could happen, or, at least, not what you're thinking should](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15595493/968261), also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3592557/968261).

You need to use proper synchronization primitives like mutexes.

Answer (score 6):

You can lock it with mutex. I assume you use pthread.

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
flag=1;
pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex);
```

Here is a very good tutorial about pthreads, mutexes and other stuff: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Comment: Keep in mind that C11 actually has a optional [thread support library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread).

Comment: I assume I would use the mutex in `memory_stats()`, outside the `while` loop. Does that allow the function to be executed again by the thread?

Comment: You can lock it outside while loop but why would you do that? It seems you just read some stuff at the beginning of the while loop. The critical region is reached when you are setting flag ?

Comment: @Zeta, C11 also has `atomic_flag` which could be use to implement exactly the scheme from the question

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be solved with a C compiler that follows the latest C standard, C11. C11 has threads and a data type called `atomic_flag`, that can basically used for a spin lock as you have it in your question.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the variable `flag` needs to be declared `volatile` or else the compiler has license to omit reads to it after the first one.

With that out of the way, a sequencer/event_counter can be used: one thread may increment the variable when it's odd, the other when it's even. Since one thread always "owns" the variable, and transfers the ownership with the increment, there is no race condition.

Comment: `volatile` in C is not sufficient to guarantee atomic access so the solution you propose would still have a race condition.

Comment: Hardware assures atomic access if the value is small enough, e.g., 32 bits. There is no race if only one of the two threads can write the value in any state.

Comment: `Hardware assures atomic access if the value is small enough` - That sounds like an platform-dependent behavior.  Not great if you want your code to be platform independent.

Comment: Do you know any machine where a one byte access is not atomic? The algorithm I proposed only needs one bit.