# When run an infintie loop why int or char gives negative value at the end

Tags: c, data-structures, char, integer

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    signed char x = 0;
    for (; x >= 0; x++);
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is -128. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: _"...When signed integer arithmetic operation overflows (the result does not fit in the result type), the __behavior is undefined__, — the possible manifestations of such an operation include:..."_ see - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Overflows

Comment: @Jarod42: There is no undefined overflow here. The behavior is implementation-defined, not undefined. Per C 2018 6.5.2.4, `x++` behaves like `x += 1`. Per 6.5.16.2, `x += 1` behaves like `x = x+1` except the lvalue `x` is evaluated only once. Per 6.5.16.1, `x = x+1` converts the right side to the type of the left side. Per 6.3.1.3 3, when the right side cannot be represented in the new type (as when the right side is 128 for a left side that is eight-bit two’s complement `signed char`), either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

Comment: @RichardCritten: There is no undefined behavior here, per my above comment.

Comment: @molbdnilo: There is no undefined behavior here. See above comments and [chux’ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68976703/298225).

Comment: @EricPostpischil The Q was tagged C++ when I commented - https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.pre#4

Comment: @RichardCritten: In C++, as in C, the operands are promoted to `int`, there is no overflow in the addition, the sum is converted to `signed char`, and the result is implementation-defined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: one of the implementation defined might be infinite loop which is UB (at least in C++, original tag) :-).

Comment: @Jarod42: The C standard requires the implementation to define the behavior of the conversion, which must either be to return a value that the implementation defines or to raise a signal that the implementation defines. The implementation may not define the behavior of the conversion to cause the loop to be an infinite loop. C++ is the same in this regard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Chux's answer state that value might stay at 127, so infinite loop

Comment: @Jarod42: Yes, the implementation can define the value resulting from the conversion in such a way that an infinite loop results in this particular code. It cannot, however, define the behavior of the conversion to cause an infinite loop; i.e., it cannot state that wherever such a conversion appears, the loop it is in will not or might not terminate. What it can define is limited. Regardless, there is no undefined behavior here.

Comment: `for (;;);` is UB in C++ ([optimizing-away-a-while1-in-c0x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592557/optimizing-away-a-while1-in-c0x)) (but not in C ([is-an-empty-infinite-loop-undefined-behavior-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595493/is-an-empty-infinite-loop-undefined-behavior-in-c))).

Comment: @EricPostpischil I stand corrected (learning is fun) but I think it might be well defined in the latest draft https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#3 then https://eel.is/c++draft/conv#integral-3

Comment: @EricPostpischil: operands are promoted to `int` only if `sizeof(char) < sizeof(int)` ;) (we can have both equal to 1 (with "big" char)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Implementation-defined behavior**

`signed char x = 0; for (; x >= 0; x++);` iterates `x` from 0 up to 127 (`SCHAR_MAX`), all OK so far.

On the next iteration, `x++` acting like `x = x + 1;`, attempts to assign 128 to the `signed char x`.  As that is out of `signed char` range:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.
> (C spec relating to conversions to a signed type)

A common implementation-defined result is to wrap around to -128 or `SCHAR_MIN`.  Other results could have happened, like assigning a max value of 127 resulting in an infinitive loop.

There is no signed integer overflow, just an out of range assignment.

---

Code is not highly portable and should be avoided.

Answer (score -1):

It is implementation-defined behaviour.

on x86 platform all known to me compilers, when `x` is 127 and you add `1` it performs unsigned addition and the result is 0b10000000 which in two's complement signed integer format is `-128`

As `x` is `-128` the loop terminates and `-128` is printed out

Comment: Half right. The behavior is implementation-defined. It is defined by the C implementation, largely the compiler, not by the “platform.” C compilers may deliver any behavior permitted by the C standard; they are not obligated to use the instruction set mindlessly.